# How do I fetch a value from multiple select used by asmselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have my code with a form.
I validate this with a javascript function sub().
When validation successful inside the javascript function i post to a php file by $.POST.
I can fetch the name field by its id name.
But I cant fetch the Cities as it has multiple value.
I am using jquery asmselect for multiple selection.
Can any one help me to fetch the multiple values of cities.
I tried by its id but failed to do.
Plz help me.............

My javascript code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.asmselect.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.asmselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[multiple]").asmSelect({
            addItemTarget: 'bottom',
            animate: true,
            highlight: true,
            sortable: true
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sub(){ 
        var udt;
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var cities = document.getElementById('cities').value;
        if(name!=""&&cities!=""){
            udt ="name="+name+"&cities="+cities;
            $.post( "submit.php", udt, function( data ) {
                window.location.href = "/"; 
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("Please, Complete the Registration Form...");
            return false;   
        }   
    }   
</script>
```

My html code is below

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return sub()" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>      
    <select id="cities" multiple="multiple" name="cities[]" title="Select City">
        <option>Paris</option>
        <option>San Diego</option>
        <option>San Francisco</option>
        <option>Vancouver</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Plz help me to solve my problem.
I can not find any solution. So I post this question here, thanks.

Comment: Check this [example](http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html) and the source code [here](https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/jquery-asmSelect/tree/master/examples)

Comment: I want to access the multiple cities values inside javascript and post to the submit.php file..............

Comment: `$('#cities').val()` will give you the selected values like  this `["Paris", "San Diego", "San Francisco"]`. You can access this array and submit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (add whatever delimiter you want):

```
cities = '';
$("select[multiple] option:selected").each(function(){
    cities += $(this).val() + '|';
});
```